# discord.js create guild with channels with permission overwrites

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm not sure what Discord devs were thinking when they added this feature, but I can't seem to come to a conclusion as to how they excepted `Discord.GuildManager#create` to work at all, whatsoever. How can you have, for example,

```
Discord.GuildCreateOptions#channels[0] = {
    name:"example-channel",
    type:Discord.ChannelType.text,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id:
```

And that's where my code snippet would have to stop. If the guild hasn't been created yet, where in god's flat green earth am I expected to find the id of a role that doesn't even exist yet? Please tell me *I'm* the dumb one here, and one of you knows exactly how to do this in a way that is not so face-palm inducing as to cause hospital-worthy migraines from the blunt force trauma of the face-palm. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, supply the roles you want to create the guild with in the `GuildCreateOptions` same as you did with the channels. Assign them custom ids, it shouldn't matter what you put in there. And then use those ids in the overwrites. 
[image]

(screenshot from the docs)

Also if random numbers don't work as the role ids. You might have to generate your own Discord Snowflake. Or copy some random discord id, e.g. message id.

Haven't tested anything, just guessing. Hope it helps at least a little :3